# UPDATED: Reading text file into a byte array

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

For a homework assignment, I need to create a class that that can read and write Byte arrays to/from a file. I have successfully created classes that can read and write CSV and text, however I am having some difficulty, when it comes to arrays. The code below is features the class that I have written. It is largely based on my CSV class, the FileInput class http://www.devjavasoft.org/SecondEdition/SourceCode/Share/FileInput.java) and FileOutput Class (http://www.devjavasoft.org/SecondEdition/SourceCode/Share/FileOutput.java).

When running the program to read a text file I get the following error message:

```
    "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
at com.gc01.FileManager.FileInput.<init>(FileInput.java:22)
at com.gc01.FileManager.ByteManager.readByte(ByteManager.java:28)
at com.gc01.FileManager.ByteManager.main(ByteManager.java:85)"
```

And my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;


public class ByteManager {

public String getByteFile(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the file directory of the chosen txt file?");
    System.out.println("For Example: /Users/UserName/Downloads/FileName.txt");
    ///Users/ReeceAkhtar/Desktop/FileName.txt
    final String fileName = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("How many columns are in the file?");
    final int columns = sc.nextByte();
    System.out.println("How many rows are in the file?");
    final int rows = sc.nextByte();
    return fileName;
    }



public void readByte(final String fileName, int columns,  int rows){
    FileInput in = new FileInput(fileName);
    int [] [] data = new int[rows] [columns];   
    String [] line;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        line = in.readString().split("\t");
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; i++){

            data [i][j] = Byte.parseByte(line[j]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("******File Read*****"); 
}   


public String chooseFileOutput(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the file directory for the output of the chosen file");
    System.out.println("For Example: /Users/UserName/Downloads/FileName.txt");
    ///Users/ReeceAkhtar/Desktop/GeoIPCountryWhois.csv
    final String fileNameOUT = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("How many columns are in the file?");
    final int columnsOut = sc.nextByte();
    System.out.println("How many rows are in the file?");
    final int rowsOut = sc.nextByte();
    return fileNameOUT;
    }

public void writeByte(final String fileNameOUT,  int columnsOut, int rowsOut){
    FileOutput createData = new FileOutput (fileNameOUT);
    int newData = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter data. To finish, enter 'TERMINATE_FILE'");

    while(!"TERMINATE_FILE".equals(newData)){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int [] [] data = new int[rowsOut] [columnsOut]; 
        String [] line = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < rowsOut; i++){
            createData.writeInteger(newData = input.nextByte());
            System.out.println("\t");
            for (int j = 0; j < columnsOut; i++){
                data [i][j] = Byte.parseByte(line[j]);  
            } 
        }   
        createData.close();
    }   
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    final ByteManager object = new ByteManager ();

    System.out.println("1 for Read File, 2 for Write file");
    String choice = in.nextLine();
    if("1".equals(choice)){
        object.getByteFile();
        object.readByte(null, 0, 0);
    } else if ("2".equals(choice)){
        object.chooseFileOutput();
        object.writeByte(null, 0, 0);
    } else{
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

}

---

UPDATE

Thank you for your comments and advice below, I have now run into a another problem that I can not work out. I have re-written my readByte method. However when I now run it, I no longer get compiler errors (thanks to your advice), however I can not get the contents of the file to print. Instead the console just displays "File Read". I have studied various resources yet I can not find the solution. I am sure it is a simple mistake somewhere. The contents of the file I am trying to read is also below.

```
public String getByteFile(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the file directory of the chosen txt file?");
    System.out.println("For Example: /Users/UserName/Downloads/FileName.txt");
    ///Users/ReeceAkhtar/Desktop/FileName.txt
    final String fileName = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("How many columns are in the file?");
    final int columns = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many rows are in the file?");
    final int rows = sc.nextInt();
    return fileName;
    }



public void readByte(final String fileName, int rows,int columns){

BufferedReader br = null;

String[] line;
String splitBy =  "\t";
int [][] data = new int[rows] [columns];


try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));  
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            line = br.toString().split(splitBy);
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
                data[i] [j] = Integer.parseInt(line[j]);
                System.out.println(data[i][j]);
            }
        }       
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {   
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } finally {  
        if (br != null) {  
        try {  
        br.close();  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("*****File Read*****");
}
```

---

File Contents (separated by tab)

---

```
123     6565
123     6564
123     6563
123     6562
```

Comment: You are passing `null` to your constructor. What file are you trying to read from or write to?

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the complier errors, yet as you will see above I am now running into another problem. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This code is the source of the error

```
object.readByte(null, 0, 0);
```

The parameter `null` is invalid state for `FileInput`. It should be a file name string.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `null` argument to `readByte()` from `main()`

```
object.readByte(null, 0, 0);
```

And in `readByte()`

```
FileInput in = new FileInput(fileName); //here it throws NPE
```

Pass valid file name.

[NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)

```
public class NullPointerException
    extends RuntimeException
```

Thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required. These include:

- Calling the instance method of a null object.
- **Accessing or modifying the field of a null object.**
- Taking the length of null as if it were an array.
- Accessing or modifying the slots of null as if it were an array.
- Throwing null as if it were a Throwable value.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I need to put the getByteFile method inside the the readByte constructor!

Comment: Aniket, do you have ideas what is going wrong with the updated code?

Thanks again!

Comment: @ReeceAkhtar : Where is `main()` method in updated code? This is getting really long question. You can post new question with updated code or post here.

Comment: Following your advice, I have created a separate post found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662210/having-difficulties-creating-a-program-that-reading-and-writing-2d-arrays-to-fro  Hope you can help!

Comment: @ReeceAkhtar : I saw your post just. I found solution. Happy to see that.